# Finding the right transition from a song lyric

Tags: synonyms

I am writing an essay about my interest in the band Queen's songs. I want to start the essay with a lyric from one of their songs and slowly transition to how it makes me feel. For example,

"Mama..Just killed a man" **Queen would sing** and I would be plunged into a whole new world.

The boldened portion just doesn't sound right to me. Any suggestions on how to improve it are appreciated.

Comment: Apologies, but writing advice is off-topic on EL&U. You might like to have a look at [writing.se] instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for writing advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Hearing Queen sing those lyrics took me to a whole new world. His words plunged me into memories of...  '

Comment: Pedantry: It was Freddie Mercury who sang that line, not the whole band.